# Differential equqtions_bernoulli's equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation as a bernoulli?
The equation is:

> $$(x-\frac 1 y)dy=\frac {dx} x$$

I don't know what the change of variable I must make is,I know that I must use $z=y^{(1-m)}$ ,but what should m be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x-\frac 1 y)dy=\frac {dx} x$$

$$(x-\frac 1 y)x=\frac {dx} {dy}$$

Bernouilli's equation:

$$ x'=x^2-\frac x y$$

Divide by $x^2$:

$$ \frac {x'}{x^2}=1-\frac 1 {xy}$$

$$ (\frac {-1}{x})'=1-\frac 1 {xy}$$

Substitute $z=\frac 1 x$

$$ -z'=1-\frac z y$$

$$ z'=\frac z y -1$$

$$ z'-\frac z y =-1$$

Can you take it from there ? It's an ordinary first differential equation.

Comment: Yes thank you but I thought that z must be in terms of y not x

Comment: it wont work if you try that way with this equation ( nothing to do with bernouilli) @Fifi